# RavenDb Transformers and Authorization Bundle

Tags: ravendb

I have the following code:

```
_session.SecureFor(requester.Id, Authorization
                .AuthorizationPermissionsMessageView);

var messages = _session.Query<Message<T>>()
                    .TransformWith<MessagesForAccountByCreatorId, Message<T>>();
```

This always yields _all of the Messages no matter what the authorization on them is.

when i do this:

```
_session.SecureFor(requester.Id, Authorization
                .AuthorizationPermissionsMessageView);

var messages = _session.Query<Message<T>>();
```

I only get the Messages the user has permission to view.

So am I right in thinking the Auth bundle is only good for direct queries? It does not work in indexes and transformers?

So I see the following from the docs:

"While documents queried using an index will be filtered according to the security rules, there isn't any filtering for fetching the data done directly from the index. Fetching data from the index requires an explicit action (marking the field as stored), so it isn't usually a concern, but be aware that even with the Auth Bundle, if you are storing fields in the indexes, they can be read regardless of the authorization setup you have."

I'm confused by that! What does that mean? It says security filters apply to indexes and then says they aren't?!

Totally confused now, [Ayende says here they are supported](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/ravendb/EvZxhlh__s0/ZICz5cKe50QJ).

Comment: Your test is passing: https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/blob/master/Bundles/Raven.Bundles.Tests/Authorization/Bugs/Wayne/QueryTransformer.cs

Comment: Weird :/ I'll have to see where I am muddling things up. Thanks for looking into it